# Trying to use Replace to replace background-position part with Regex to parse URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace this string `url(http://www.yahoo.com/someimage)`

```
var url  = $(someelement).css("background-image"); //url(http://www.yahoo.com/someimage)

var path = url.replace(/url(\()|(\))/, '');
```

I have tried a few ways but I can't seem to get the end parenthesis.  I am not sure what I need to do to write this correctly.

Comment: Match the `^`start and end `$` of the string, and let it know it is `g`lobal for two matches; `/^url\(|\)$/g`

Comment: sigh, so close! thanks!

Comment: Do not forget that quote (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) could be used in `url()`.

Comment: You should submit that as an answer @PaulS. so other people may find it :}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match the `^`start and end`$` of the string, and let it know it is `g`lobal for two matches;

```
/^url\(|\)$/g
```

You could also make it optionally look for quotes like this

```
/^url\(['"]?|['"]?\)$/g
```